# Missing rows in PerformancePoint Dashboard chart compared to Excel Services

Tags: 2010, excel-services, performancepoint

Excel which is published has more than 75 rows but in dashboard there are only 75 rows for the report.Are there any parameters are set for this in dashboard designer or any other changes are required.

Thanks,
Gautam Shukla